# Openpyxl - trouble naming workbook

Tags: python, xlsx, openpyxl

I have a python script that analyses a file tree and records its findings in an xlsx.

Analysis is going fine, but when I try to record my results, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\call_validation.py", line 103, in <module>
    wb.save(wb_name)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 298, i
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 196, in sav
    writer.save(filename, as_template=as_template)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 178, in sav
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED)
  File "C:\Python\lib\zipfile.py", line 923, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, modeDict[mode])
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'move_generated-2015-05-07 10:08:26.xlsx'
```

I am generating my filename using `datetime.datetime.now()` like so:

```
save_time = str(datetime.datetime.now()).split(".")[0]
wb_name = "move_generated-" + save_time + ".xlsx"
wb.save(wb_name)
```

I don't believe the filename is too long, its only in `C:\code\call_flow`  and I've tried stripping all the non-alphanumeric characters out of the name.  Any ideas?

EDIT:  Solution ended up being that I had failed to strip the colons from the time.  As @nivix zixer said I fixed it by replacing

```
save_time = str(datetime.datetime.now()).split(".")[0]
```

with

```
save_time = str(datetime.datetime.now()).split(".")[0].replace(':', '_')
```

Comment: Perhaps the problem is you have a space in the filename? Try replacing your `str(datetime.datetime.now()).split(".")[0]` with this: `str(datetime.datetime.now()).split(".")[0].replace(' ', '_')`

Comment: Thanks, that was what I needed.  If you want to post an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Just format the `datetime` using `strftime` next time.https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the problem is you have a space in the filename?

Replace `str(datetime.datetime.now()).split(".")[0]` with this: `str(datetime.datetime.now()).split(".")[0].replace(' ', '_')`.

Glad I could help Will!